# Getting an error "TypeError: undefined is not observable"

Tags: angular, typeahead, ng2-bootstrap

I'm using angular2 and ng2-bootstrap.

My typeahead is setup as follows:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="selectedAsset"
               [typeahead]="assets"
               (typeaheadOnSelect)="typeaheadOnSelect($event)"
               class="form-control">
```

As soon as I type in the input box I get this error:

```
typeahead.directive.js:189 TypeError: undefined is not observable
```

Comment: Seems like you are passing an undefined model to directive. Try defining models in your controller and then pass it on. Btw, this is just a guess.

Comment: Also getting this error:

  Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/moment

found the solution here:   https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/issues/442

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lots of searching and reading I eventually found the problem.

The name of the assets list in my typescript file was different to the html

```
private assets: Array<string> = [];
private selectedAsset: string='';
```

As long as those two are in the component.ts file (and are correctly spelt) it all works brilliantly.

Comment: Yep I can confirm this. Capitals also matter ;-) Thanks Peter.